# Cannot add Azure AD authentication to existing app

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I created an Asp.Net Core Mvc app that uses Azure AD authentication using the wizard (the "test app") and it works fine.  The real app that I need to plug in to Azure AD authentication already exists and it's also an Asp.Net Core Mvc app (the "real app").  I thought it would be quick work to simply add what was in the "test app" that was missing from the "real app"...not so.  Adding the missing pieces (the "canned" VS code) and getting the app to compile and run was easy, making authentication work has been an all-day head banging exercise in futility.

Azure consistently returns:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application: 'xxxxxxx'.

What seems to be the issue is passing the ClientSecret.  I noticed that the "test app" has an auto-generated file called usersecretsassemblyinfo.cs, and in spite of adding my clientsecret following this doc (which seems outdated): 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio, the file is never generated by VS.  I can only assume there's another tool that generates it (or the names and places of the details have been changed to protect the innocent).

Also I've doubled checked the azure 'app registrations' and the one for the "real app" is virtually identical to the one for the "test app", with the exception of the keys of course.

Also recreating the "real app" is not an option for a lot of reasons I can't get into here.

Comment: The error is pretty clear though? It sounds like your reply URLs in the app registration do not match the URL the app is using.

Comment: Reply URL in 'real app' is the same (except for port) as the reply url in 'test app'.

Comment: Port must be same too :) I mean same as what your app uses. Check the redirect_uri in the login URL. It needs to match the reply URL

Comment: As junnas said, you should check the redirect_uri in your real app and the reply URLs in AAD app. If your real app is published for production, the reply URL will be changed to `<yourappURL>/signin-oidc` You'd better check the `tenantId` and `client Id` in `appsettings.json` file too.